# Use net.server to handle http and express all at once

Tags: node.js, handle

i have a server using `net.Server` and also have 2 servers using `http.Server` and `express()`. and it looks like this

```
...
var s_net = net.createServer();
var s_http = http.createServer();
var s_exp = express();
s_net.listen(opt.port);
s_http.listen(s_net);
s_exp.listen(s_net);
console.log(`listening on ${opt.port}`);
```

I use `s_net` as a handler for `s_http` and `s_exp`. and then, i do

```
s_net.on("connection", function(c){
    console.log("incoming connection to s_net")
})
s_http.on("request", function(req, res){
    console.log("request to s_http");
});
s_exp.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("request to s_exp");
    res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
});
```

but on console, i just get

```
H:\NodeJS\web3>node index.js
listening on 80
request to s_exp
```

where does, it only respond from `s_exp` request. 
How can I got them all? 
`incoming connection to s_net`, `request to s_http`, and `request to s_exp`

references : 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/net.html#net_server_listen_handle_backlog_callback

Comment: What's the point?  Just make one Express server and then apply any event listeners you want to it.  It will have an http server under the covers which is also a TCP server under the covers.

Comment: What's the point? there isn't

Comment: I do it for... ya. i dont know. I want to get them all together. I just made something that useless. But, maybe, I want to get fresh request without any changes and I want to link it to http and express together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a server using Express, you already have an http server.  It's just an http server that has Express as a request handler for incoming requests.  And, an http server inherits from `net.Server` so it's already a TCP/IP server.  Create the one express server and then you can use any express, http or net.Server features on it including setting event listeners for various server events.

So, just creating a generic Express server already has all three together.  There is no need or point to creating three separate servers and then trying to combine them somehow.